# how do i make an invisible text input box visible on hover?

Tags: css, html, input, hover, invisible

It doesn't seem to work for me!

**HTML**

```
 <div id="box1">
     <form action="">
         <input type="string" name="htmlcode" />
     </form>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-color:black 4px
}
input {
    display:none;
}
a:hover input{
    display:block;
}
```

the text input is either invisible, or visible but does not respond to hover

Answer (score 4):

You don't have an `a` tag that you can hover to show the input...

Change it to `#box1:hover input{display:block;}` so it will show when you move your mouse into the box.

`border-color:black 4px` is also invalid. If you want to set the border color, you can only give it a color, not a color and size.

Here's a [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/evujay/1/) showing both of those things fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `<a>` in `html`. Try: `div:hover input{display:block;}`

Answer (score 1):

in your css you need to add this

```
#box1:hover input{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 #box1 { 
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:4px solid black;
}
 input {display:none;}
 #box1:hover input{display:block;}​
```

As others mentioned, you don't have an `a` tag so change the target of the `:hover` as well.

Also fixed the border declaration.

http://jsfiddle.net/XZvHh/

Comment: The box has fixed size so you don't need visibility. Display will work just fine in this case.

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't mean to say using visibility was incorrect.